# Vue js el.offsetHeight return wrong result

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get the height of the element. The problem is that this.$refs.head.offsetHeight returns the wrong number (188), but the console.dir(this.$refs.head); returns true height 794

[image: console.dir]

```
mounted(){
 console.dir(this.$refs.head);
 console.log(this.$refs.head.offsetHeight);
}
```

Comment: The element's conent is probably still loading or changing between your logs and the time you click "expand". Is `this.$refs` a frame?

Comment: this.$refs.head is div element

Comment: If you put a `debugger` statement in your `mounted` hook you'll be able to see exactly what is being measured in the DOM. The appropriate fix would depend on what exactly we're waiting for.